# How to click on the button as per the html through Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am trying to find and click this button using selenium:

```
<button class="orangeButton nextStep js-submitForm js-pop" data-href="/user/welcome/subscribe">Take me to my Subscriptions</button>
```

However, there is no id and the classname is too long so i want to use xpath. However, i dont understand how to use it..

Current code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='orangeButton nextStep js-submitForm js-pop\'")).Click();
```

But this fails as not a valid xpath argument

Comment: Try to remove redundant back-slash and close predicate with square bracket: `"//button[@class='orangeButton nextStep js-submitForm js-pop']"`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  You can't treat the classes separated by spaces as one class string.  The space means it is a different class, and you have to treat each individually.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'orangeButton') and contains(@class, 'nextStep') and contains(@class, 'js-submitForm') and contains(@class, 'js-pop')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use all classes to locate an element, only those that make element unique.

By css:

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.nextStep"));
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.orangeButton.nextStep"));
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.orangeButton.nextStep.js-submitForm.js-pop"));
```

By xpath and class:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(@class,'orangeButton) and contains(@class,'nextStep)'"));
```

By xpath and text:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//button[normalize-space(., 'Take me to my Subscriptions')"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have shared the desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@class='orangeButton nextStep js-submitForm js-pop' and contains(@data-href,'subscribe')][contains(.,'Take me to my Subscriptions')]"))).Click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button.orangeButton.nextStep.js-submitForm.js-pop[data-href$='subscribe']"))).Click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

there are no. of ways you can try by xpath ,just give a try for below xpath expressions:

```
"//button[@class='orangeButton nextStep js-submitForm js-pop']"
"//*[@class='orangeButton nextStep js-submitForm js-pop']"
"//*[contains(@class,'orangeButton nextStep js-submitForm js-pop')]"
"//*[contains(@class,'orangeButton')]" // contains() can accept partial text as well
```

Also check below (if works or not)

```
"//*[contains(@data-href,'/user/welcome/subscribe')]"
"//*[contains(@data-href,'subscribe')]"
```

by using AND and or OR

```
"//*[@class='orangeButton nextStep js-submitForm js-pop' and @data-href='/user/welcome/subscribe']"
"//*[@class='orangeButton nextStep js-submitForm js-pop' OR @data-href='/user/welcome/subscribe']"
```